# convert Two lat and LNG to string "8 miles away"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, latitude-longitude

I can't seem to convert two lat and LNG to a string. By the time I convert to degrees and back to a string I get large numbers like 999737 for what should be 2 miles or less away.

OK works!

Comment: Come back later and supply the code please, otherwise we can't help you. Crystal ball debugging is very hard.

Comment: We don't really care that you can't post your code since you're on a phone. In its current state, this is not a real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can convert between double -> string & back from string -> double

```
//Defining Latitude & Longitude    
NSNumber *latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:31.5497226715];
NSNumber *longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:74.3436126709];
NSLog(@"Origional > Lat: %.10f, Lng: %.10f", [latitude doubleValue], [longitude doubleValue]);

//Conversion to string
NSString *latitudeStr = [latitude stringValue];
NSString *longitudeStr = [longitude stringValue];
NSLog(@"String > Lat: %@, Lng: %@", latitudeStr, longitudeStr);


//String to double
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSNumber *latitudeFromStr = [numberFormatter numberFromString:latitudeStr];
NSNumber *longitudeFromStr = [numberFormatter numberFromString:longitudeStr];

[numberFormatter release];

NSLog(@"Back from string > Lat: %.10f, Lng: %.10f", [latitudeFromStr doubleValue], [longitudeFromStr doubleValue]);
```

Comment: Abduliam, you rock.  Thank you. And love your attitude.

Comment: @jgervin my pleasure, its why we are here, helping each other. Actually @stackoverflow.com rocks for providing such awesome service.